# Why does this causes the application to hang

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task-parallel-library, deadlock

The code below is causing my WPF application to get hung (likely dead-locks). I have verified that DownloadStringAsTask method is executed on a separate (non-UI) thread. Interestingly if you uncomment the messagebox line (just before call to while (tasks.Any()), application works fine. Can anyone explain why do application hungs at first place and also how to resolve this issue?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame x:Name="frame"  Grid.Row="0" />
        <StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Grid.Row="1" >
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Name="tbStatusBar" Text="Waiting for getting update" />
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>



public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<string> URLsToProcess = new List<string>
        {
             "http://www.microsoft.com",
             "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
             "http://www.google.com",
             "http://www.apple.com",
             "http://www.ebay.com",
             "http://www.oracle.com",
             "http://www.gmail.com",
             "http://www.amazon.com",
             "http://www.outlook.com",
             "http://www.yahoo.com",
             "http://www.amazon124.com",
             "http://www.msn.com"
         };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ProcessURLs();
    }

    public void ProcessURLs()
    {
         var tasks = URLsToProcess.AsParallel().Select(uri => DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(uri))).ToArray();
         //MessageBox.Show("this is doing some magic"); 
         while (tasks.Any())
         {
             try
             {
                 int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
                 this.tbStatusBar.Text = string.Format("{0} has completed", tasks[index].AsyncState.ToString());
                 tasks = tasks.Where(t => t != tasks[index]).ToArray();
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 foreach (var t in tasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted))
                     this.tbStatusBar.Text = string.Format("{0} has completed", t.AsyncState.ToString());
                 tasks = tasks.Where(t => t.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted).ToArray();
             }
         }   
    }

    private Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address)
     {
         TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(address);
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
         {
             if (args.Error != null)
                 tcs.SetException(args.Error);
             else if (args.Cancelled)
                 tcs.SetCanceled();
             else
                 tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
         };
         client.DownloadStringAsync(address);
         return tcs.Task;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that your constructor does not return until all of the tasks have completed. Until the constructor returns, the window will not be shown, because the window messages related to drawing the window aren't going to be processed.

Note that you don't really have "deadlock" here per se. Instead, if you waited long enough (i.e. until all the tasks have completed), the window would actually be shown.

When you add the call to `MessageBox.Show()`, you give the UI thread a chance to process the window message queue. That is, the normal modal dialog includes a thread message pump which winds up handling those messages in the queue, including those related to showing your window. Note that even if you add the `MessageBox.Show()`, that won't result in the window being updated as your processing progresses. It just allows the window to be shown before you block the UI thread again.

One way to address this is to switch to the `async`/`await` pattern. For example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var _ = ProcessURLs();
}

public async Task ProcessURLs()
{
    List<Task<string>> tasks = URLsToProcess.Select(uri => DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(uri))).ToList();

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        Task<string> task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        string messageText;

        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            messageText = string.Format("{0} has completed", task.AsyncState);
            // TODO: do something with task.Result, i.e. the actual downloaded text
        }
        else
        {
            messageText = string.Format("{0} has completed with failure: {1}", task.AsyncState, task.Status);
        }

        this.tbStatusBar.Text = messageText;
        tasks.Remove(task);
    }

    tbStatusBar.Text = "All tasks completed";
}
```

I've rewritten the `ProcessURLs()` method as an `async` method. This means that when the constructor calls it, it will run synchronously up to the first `await` statement, at which point it will yield and allow the current thread to continue normally.

When the call to `Task.WhenAny()` completes (i.e. any of the tasks complete), the runtime will resume execution of the `ProcessURLs()` method by invoking the continuation on the UI thread. This allows the method to access the UI objects (e.g. `this.tbStatusBar.Text`) normally, while occupying the UI thread only long enough to process the completion.

When the loop returns to the top and the `Task.WhenAny()` method is called again, the whole sequence is repeated (i.e. just the way a loop is supposed to work :) ).

Some other notes:

- The `var _ =` bit in the constructor is there to suppress the compiler warning that would otherwise occur when the `Task` return value is ignored.
- IMHO, it would be better to not initialize these operations in the constructor. The constructor is just generally a bad place to be doing significant work like this. Instead, I would (for example) override the `OnActivated()` method, making it `async` so you can use the `await` statement with the call to `ProcessURLs()` (i.e. a more idiomatic way to call an `async` method). This ensures the window is completely initialized and shown before you start doing any other processing.

In this particular example, starting the processing in the constructor is probably not really going to hurt anything, as long as you're using `async`/`await`, since the UI-related stuff isn't going to be able to be executed in any case until at least the constructor has returned. I just try to avoid doing this sort of thing in the constructor as a general rule.

- I also modified the general handling of your task collection, to something that I feel is somewhat more suitable. It gets rid of the repeated reinitialization of the `tasks` collection, as well as takes advantage of the semantics of the `WhenAny()` method. I also removed the `AsParallel()`; given that the long-running part of the processing is handled asynchronously already, there did not seem to be any advantage in the attempt to parallelize the `Select()` itself.

Comment: `Instead, if you waited long enough (i.e. until all the tasks have completed), the window would actually be shown` - wrong. Just try running the code.

Comment: @Lanorkin: I did run the code and it worked exactly as I describe.

Answer (score 1):

The likely cause for the hang is that you are mixing sync and asnyc code and calling WaitAny. Stephen Cleary has post that is useful in understanding common issues with Tasks.
[Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Here is a solution that simplifies your code and uses Parallel.ForEach

**Code**

```
public partial class WaitAnyWindow : Window {

  private List<string> URLsToProcess = new List<string>
      {
            "http://www.microsoft.com",
            "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
            "http://www.google.com",
            "http://www.apple.com",
            "http://www.ebay.com",
            "http://www.oracle.com",
            "http://www.gmail.com",
            "http://www.amazon.com",
            "http://www.outlook.com",
            "http://www.yahoo.com",
            "http://www.amazon.com",
            "http://www.msn.com"
        };

  public WaitAnyWindow02() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Parallel.ForEach(URLsToProcess, (x) => DownloadStringFromWebsite(x));
  }

  private bool DownloadStringFromWebsite(string website) {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
      if (e.Error != null)
      {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
          this.tbStatusBar.Text = string.Format("{0} didn't complete because {1}", website, e.Error.Message);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
          this.tbStatusBar.Text = string.Format("{0} has completed", website);
        }));
      }
    };

    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(website));

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I agree with Peter about not putting the code in the constructor.